# Update UI element from a different thread in Windows 8/WinRT

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have a button and a textblock in a Windows 8 "Metro" application. When the button is clicked it calls a webservice via HttpWebRequest.

```
private void buttonGo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/");

    req.BeginGetResponse(ResponseCallback, req);
}

private void ResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)asyncResult.AsyncState;

    HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);
    Stream streamResponse = res.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
    string responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();

    info.Text = responseString; // Can't do this as outside the UI thread
}
```

I want to update `info.Text` with the data returned from the WebRequest, however it causes an error: *"The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread."* I understand that this is because it is not being called from the UI thread.

I have found various different solutions involving `Dispatcher`, `SynchronizationContext`, the `await` keyword.

What is the easiest/best way to do this?

Comment: I haven't used WinRT specifically, but I imagine it would be something like `info.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => info.Text = responseString);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Windows Store app you really should use the async await pattern for all asynchronous calls - it is the simplest and most effective way. You can rewrite your existing code to use this pattern as follows:

```
private async void buttonGo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/");

    HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)(await req.GetResponseAsync());
    Stream streamResponse = res.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
    // all IO operations should be called asynchronously
    string responseString = await streamRead.ReadToEndAsync();

    info.Text = responseString; // This way the code runs on UI thread
}
```

The code after each await keyword is effectively behaving as if it was in a callback but it always executes on the UI thread so that you don't have to worry about it.

All IO bound operations in APIs for Windows Store apps are available in asynchronous flavor. You should prefer them over synchronous ones even when both are available to prevent blocking of UI thread - such as in `ReadToEndAsync` example above.

Answer (score 4):

Like Damir said we really should use the async/await pattern but sometimes it's simply necessary to update the UI in a worker thread (task). This is done using the current CoreDispatcher that dispatches the invocation to the UI thread:

```
private void ResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
   ...

   this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
   {
      info.Text = responseString;
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest and best:

```
private async void buttonGo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
    info.Text = await client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost/");
  }
}
```

Under the covers, `await` captures the current `SynchronizationContext` and resumes the method in that context. The Win8/WinRT `SynchronizationContext` in turn uses the `Dispatcher`.

Comment: If I specifically want to set info.Text from within the ResponseCallback, how would I do it?

Comment: Well, you could use `TaskCompletionSource` to wrap the entire callback in a `Task<T>` and then use code just like I posted. Or you can capture the `SynchronizationContext` and do your thread marshaling manually. Not sure why you would ever do that these days, though.

Comment: One reason is if you are on .net 4.0 and want your async to provide progress.  If using .net 4.5 and latter they have IProgress<> or Progress<> so you can just use TaskCompletionSource if I understand correctly. On .net 4.0 your out of luck so you would need to use a SynchronizationContext to pass progress to the caller?

Comment: @Wes: [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async` has `Progress<T>`](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/1.0.168/net40/doc/Microsoft.Progress'1). Alternatively, you could use Reactive Extensions or `SynchronizationContext` directly.

Comment: With Microsoft.Bcl.Async you need KB2468871 installed which most users probably do have installed. We're still on .net 4.0 and I couldn't find a sure fire way to check if that update is installed so I decided not to use that library. Plus it would add another 20MB to our installer which has to work offline.  I wasn't aware of Reactive Extensions so got to check that out.

Comment: @Wes: You should be able to bundle the update with your installer. I did, half-a-decade ago or so.